# Xslt collection as parameter

Tags: .net, xslt, input, parameters, collections

Could you help me to answer how to put collection of data as parameter in the xslt file, is it possible ? Thanks.

Comment: platform .net, processor visual studio 2010, and I want to added collection of data into the xslt file, I know how to add one or more parameters as string and currently I need added collection , may be string with separated symbols or something like this, and in the xslt file parse this string and foreach on it, is it possible ?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you can pass a param with any XPath/XSLT data type (not only string, but also node set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

`<xsl:param name="chunks" select="collection('file:///C:/test_xml?*.xml')"/>`

loads all of the `.xml` files in the `C:\text_xml` directory into the parameter `chunks`.

Is this what you were looking for?

*Note: This was done using Saxon-PE 9.2

Comment: something like this but without extension(or .net extension)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want document() ?

http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp

Answer (score 0):

In .Net you need to pass a `XsltArgumentList` object to the `Transform` method as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882.aspx

Comment: I know about XsltArgumentList and also, it is extension of .net platform, I'll try example with collection()

Comment: @jitm: Well, but you have accepted an answer for XSLT 2.0 processor (as `collection` is a core function from XPath 2.0), something VS is not.

Comment: Yes, I know about collection.